# Modification in existing code for searching in two sheets and omiting the words from phrases

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 sheets:

- Sheet1 contains phrases in column B (Example - ABD Ron Tim 001)
- Sheet2 contains list of words in column A (Example Ron, Tim, Goerge) and
- Sheet 3 contains phrases again in column A (Example 1 - ABC Tim-001), (Example 2 - THER Goerge-898).

The below code find the words present in column B sheet 1 in sheet 2 column A and if the matching words are found in the phare it then moves and matches the found words in with the entire phrase column in Sheet 3 column A and omits the words found there from the output.

The output is displayed in sheet 1 column C in adjacent cells.

The problem with this code is if in sheet 3 the words in the phrases are like `tim-001` it omits it however I want to omit if the word is matched exactly like `tim 001` where `tim` is a separate word. I also want it to be case sensitive. It would be very helpful if you could add the lines or tell me how to modify it and explain what the added lines or modified lines does.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Exec()

Dim i As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
Dim Ws3 As Worksheet
Dim IsFound As Boolean

On Error GoTo ErrHan

Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set Ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
Set Ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3)

   With Ws2
  Columns("A:A").Select
  Ws2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
 End With

For iRow = 2 To Ws1.Cells(Ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To Ws2.Cells(Ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    IsFound = False
    For j = 2 To Ws3.Cells(Ws3.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If LCase(Ws3.Cells(j, 1).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Ws2.Cells(i,             1).Value) & "*" Then IsFound = True
    Next j
    If Not IsFound And LCase(Ws1.Cells(iRow, 2).Value) Like "*" & LCase(Ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value) & "*" Then
        Ws1.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Ws1.Cells(iRow, 3).Value & "," & Ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
Next i
If InStr(1, Ws1.Cells(iRow, 3).Value, ",") > 0 Then
    Ws1.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Right(Ws1.Cells(iRow, 3).Value, Len(Ws1.Cells(iRow, 3).Value) - 1)
  End If
Next iRow

 Set Ws1 = Nothing
 Set Ws2 = Nothing
 Set Ws3 = Nothing

Exit Sub
ErrHan:
MsgBox "Sorry, an error occured:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Set Ws1 = Nothing
Set Ws2 = Nothing
Set Ws3 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you could get the output on sheet c with a worksheet formula rather than using VBA

Comment: Thanks but I need a vba instead of formula because I don't want the sheet to calculate it each time I filter data.

Answer (score 1):

If you load the sentence or phrase to an array of variant type where the words are separated by the space bar, you can loop through the array to locate exact matches without having to use the wildcard character.

```
Dim vList as variant
Dim vItem as variant

vlist = split(Ws3.Cells(j, 1).Value, " ")
for each vitem in vlist
  if instr(1, vitem, Ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0 then
    'do your replace/copy here
  endif
next vitem
```